# React-Router v6 State is null

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

This is my first time using react-router-dom and state is causing me issues, it is being returned to me as null. I have seen that there are answers here already but they do not solve my problem as I am using the provided answers as exactly as I can.

I am attempting to have a state object: `{token: boolean, setToken: function}` initialized in `App.js` to be sent down to `ProfilePage.js` (in this case specifically but later to all page components). However, in `ProfilePage.js`, state is null. I have also tried sending the string `{'hello'}` and a simple boolean `{data: true}` with no change to state

My full `App.js` code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchPage from './pages/Search.page';
import HomePage from './pages/Home.page';
import ProfilePage from './pages/Profile.page';
import AddEntryPage from './pages/AddEntry.page';
import LoginPage from "./pages/Login.page";
import CreateUserPage from "./pages/CreateUser.page";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);

  return (
      <Router>
          <div>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to='/profile' state={{token, setToken}}>Profile</Link>
                </li>
                <li className='right-edge-pusher'>
                  <Link to='/' state={{token, setToken}}>Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to='/add' state={{token, setToken}}>Add</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to='/search' state={{token, setToken}}>Search</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<HomePage /> }/>
              <Route path='/profile' element={<ProfilePage />}/>
              <Route path='/add' element={<AddEntryPage />}/>
              <Route path='/search' element={<SearchPage />}/>
              <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage /> }/>
              <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUserPage /> }/>
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My full `ProfilePage.js` code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import PostSnippet from '../components/PostSnippet';

function ProfilePage() {
    
    const { state } = useLocation();
    console.log(state);

    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

    const fetchProfile = () => {
        return axios.get("http://localhost:5000/saved")
    }
    const { data, isError, error, isLoading } = useQuery('profile', fetchProfile, { enabled });

    return ( 
        <div>
            { true /*note: will later be changed to !token*/ && 
                <>
                    <Link to={'/login'} /*state to be passed here as well*/ >Login</Link>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <Link to={'/user'} /*state to be passed here as well*/ >Create User</Link>
                </>
            }
            { isLoading && <h2>Loading...</h2> }
            { isError && <h2>{error.response.data.message.message}</h2> }
            { data && 
                data.data.map(item => {
                    return (
                        <PostSnippet 
                            key={item.id}
                            plantName={item.name}
                            plantTempRange={`${item.sow_temp_range}f`}
                            plantZone={item.planting_zone}
                            plantSunReq={`${item.sun_req} sun`}
                            plantDescription='To be added...'
                        />
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
     );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values passed in route/link state must be JSON serializable. You can't pass functions, e.g. the `setToken`, through the state, it will nullify the ***entire*** state object.

My suggestion here would be to use a React Context to pass down the `token` and `setToken` callback. The `Outlet` component is an easy and trivial way to provide this context value, and the routed components that care to read/access the value will use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook.

Example:

```
import {
  ...
  Outlet,
  ...
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
            </li>
            <li className='right-edge-pusher'>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/add">Add</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/search">Search</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            element={(
              <Outlet
                context={{token, setToken}} // <-- pass context value here
              />
            )}
          >
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage /> } />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
            <Route path="/add" element={<AddEntryPage />} />
            <Route path="/search" element={<SearchPage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage /> } />
            <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUserPage /> } />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Any component rendered within the layout route's provided outlet context can access the value as `const { token, setToken } = useOutletContext();`.

```
...
import { Link, useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';
...

function ProfilePage() {
  const { token, setToken } = useOutletContext();
  console.log({ token, setToken });

  ...

  return ( 
    ...
  );
}

export default ProfilePage;
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-state-is-null]

Comment: Thank you. I copy/pasted the code you provided but it was giving me an error. I replaced the destructured useOutletContext object to an object named context but that is still returning null.

Comment: @Jewel You might still have some issue elsewhere. The code above works as I'd expect. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-state-is-null-kcv5dt) demo. I've also provided a link to it in my answer. If you've tried implementing this solution and still have an issue feel free to fork the sandbox and add in more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue that we could then inspect live.

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake! I improperly closed the Route tag! Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

The state you have passed to the profile page can be accessed using the code provided below:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProfilePage() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { token, setToken } = location.state; // Destructure the state object 
  /*
   ....
  */
   
}
```

I hope this answer helps you resolve your scenario.

Comment: Thank you, but it returned undefined.

Comment: React Router's <Link> component only allows passing JSON serializable data, which means functions cannot be directly passed as part of the state. I think the Context API might be a good fit for your scenario.